# Using parameterized SQL query while reading large table into pandas dataframe using COPY

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, dataframe

I am trying to read a large table (10-15M rows) from a database into pandas dataframe and I'm using the following code:

```
def read_sql_tmpfile(query, db_engine):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmpfile:
        copy_sql = "COPY ({query}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV {head}".format(
           query=query, head="HEADER"
        )
        conn = db_engine.raw_connection()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.copy_expert(copy_sql, tmpfile)
        tmpfile.seek(0)
        df = pandas.read_csv(tmpfile)
        return df
```

I can use this if I have a simple query like this and I pass this into above func:

```
'''SELECT * from  hourly_data'''
```

But what if I want to pass some variable into this query i.e.

```
'''SELECT * from  hourly_data where starttime >= %s '''
```

Now where do I pass the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use parameters with `COPY`. Unfortunately that extends to the query you use inside `COPY`, even if you could use parameters with the query itself.

You will have to construct a query string including the parameter (beware of SQL injection) and use that with `COPY`.